# Mat Data type not supported error in java while using OpenCv

Tags: java, opencv, bufferedimage, mat

Below is the java code to convert buffered Image into Mat type. While I run this function I get following exception: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Mat data type is not compatible:**

```
  public static Mat bufferedImageToMat(BufferedImage image) {
  Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
  int[] data = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
  mat.put(0, 0, data);
  return mat;
}
```

I searched for the error on google also I have followed the similar kind of question in stack overflow, however, that is not helping me. Can anyone help me out here. I m stuck .

Comment: May I ask why this question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this would make a difference but you could try to change

int[] data = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData(); to

byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

I tried to recreate your error but to no avail. I only got an error when I changed my code to use an int [] instead of byte [].

Comment: I had byte earlier but still I got the same error then I converted to int which is same

Comment: Could you post the code where you are calling the method